# How to use bashful package from inside etoolbox list processing?

Tags: etoolbox, bashful

Given list of file names, I wanted to obtain the word count of each file, but by using either `\forcsvlist` or `\docsvlist` and pass the file name to bash from Latex without hardcoding the file name in the bash command, but by using the argument passed to the `\docsvlist`.

I can't get it to work.  Here is a MWE of what I am trying to do, which does not work at all

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bashful}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand*{\do}[1]{%
The file #1 has size
\bash
wc #1
\END
\bashStdout

}
\docsvlist{foo.log,foo.tex}
\end{document}
```

And now

```
 pdflatex --shell-esc  foo.tex

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
! Use of \bashIII doesn't match its definition.
<recently read> w

l.17 \docsvlist{foo.log,foo.tex}
```

I think I need to `expandafter` or `expandonce` or one of these commands Which I really still do not understand how these work or where to use them. The package [document](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) does not have many examples to help understand how to use these commands.

If I move the bash command outside, then it works of course:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bashful}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand*{\do}[1]{%
The file #1 has size

}
\docsvlist{foo.log,foo.tex}

\bash
wc foo.tex
\END
\bashStdout    
\end{document}
```

But I need to use the bash commands on the list items, pass the current list item `#1` to the bash command, and get the output of the bash command to use.

Is it possible to do the above?

TL 2015

Comment: It's always the same problem: `\bash` uses verbatim, so it can't be in the argument to another command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use `\bash` in the argument to another command, because it uses some variant of verbatim mode.

There's a simple way to solve this without extra packages, using “piped input”: if the first token in the argument to the primitive `\input` command is `|`, then the file name is taken as a shell command to execute with, essentially, the TeX file as standard output. Quotes around the file name are allowed (and recommended, in this case) both by TeX Live and MiKTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\shellcommand}[1]{\@@input"|#1"}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\renewcommand*{\do}[1]{%
  The file #1 has size \texttt{\shellcommand{wc #1}}\par
}

\docsvlist{fontaw.tex,fontaw.log}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, did not know about the `\@@input`, looks very useful.