# why is adding `breqn` package breaks `etoolbox` command?

Tags: etoolbox, breqn

I was trying egreg nice answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/257621/how-to-use-bashful-package-from-inside-etoolbox-list-processing) in my main document, and I found it does not work there. It turned out it is because I happened to be using another package which is `breqn` which I really need.

I have no idea why  `breqn` breaks the command. But here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt,notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}%see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/257621
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\shellcommand}[1]{\@@input"|#1"}
\makeatother
\usepackage{breqn}
\newcounter{c}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{c}{\shellcommand{id -g}}
\arabic{c}
\end{document}
```

compile using `lualatex -shell-esc foo.tex` and the error is

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty)) (./foo2.aux)
("|id -g!"id: invalid option -- '!'
Try 'id --help' for more information.

Runaway argument?
! Paragraph ended before \@calc@pre@scan was complete.
<to be read again> 
\par 
l.1
```

Notice the extra "!" added there.

Now simply commenting the line `\usepackage{etoolbox}` and compiling again, it works and I get the result expected. No errors.

Is there a way to keep the `breqn` and still be able to use egreg `\shellcommand` command?

When removing the `breqn` package and compiling:

```
>lualatex -shell-esc foo2.tex 
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.80.0 (TeX Live 2015) (rev 5238) 
 \write18 enabled.
(./foo2.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/01/01> patch level 2
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(./foo2.aux) ("|id -g") [1{/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/up
dmap/pdftex.map}] (./foo2.aux))
 264 words of node memory still in use:
   2 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 40 glue_spec, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 1:4,2:12,3:3,4:22,6:11,7:1,9:6
<</usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on foo2.pdf (1 page, 8298 bytes).
Transcript written on foo2.log.
>
```

The pdf contains `1000` as expected.

TL 2015 on Linux mint 12.2

Comment: I think you are misreading the output. There is a error in the shellcommand. your version of id does not know -g option

Comment: @Bort I do not undertand. The command works fine when breq package is not included.  This is a standard linux command: `id -g` gives me 1000. The error in the command was due to using the `breq` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is not due to `breqn`, but to `calc` that's automatically loaded by it. It has nothing to do with `etoolbox` either, because `\@@input` is the primitive `\input` and is defined in the kernel of LaTeX.

Here is a really minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\shellcommand}[1]{\@@input"|#1"}
\makeatother

\newcounter{c}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{c}{\shellcommand{id -g}}
\arabic{c}

\end{document}
```

The problem seems to be in how `calc` redefines `\setcounter`, so the `-` is seen as a minus sign and of course everything breaks. Here is a workaround: first compute the value you need and store it in a temporary macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,catchfile}
\usepackage{calc}

\makeatletter
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\shellcommand}{om}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
    {\@@input"|#2"}
    {\CatchFileEdef#1{"|#2"}{}}%
}
\makeatother

\newcounter{c}

\begin{document}

\shellcommand[\temp]{id -g}
\setcounter{c}{\temp}
\arabic{c}

\end{document}
```

On my machine this prints 20.

Comment: thanks. Initial test shows it works but generates  what seems to be harmless error from `lualatex` but no such message from pdflatex. When I compiled using `lualatex  -shell-esc foo.tex` I see message: `(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty)))
(./foo2.aux)id: invalid option -- '.'
Try 'id --help' for more information.`  but when I look at the pdf file, I see the group id there !  I need to test this more on my main file which does something more complicated. thanks

Comment: I have a follow-up question @egreg. I was fiddling around this subsequent my initial confusion (see above) and my "ingenious" solution was to come up with a way that the additional ! doesnt matter like: \setcounter{c}{\shellcommand{./fakeid ignoreme}}  were fakeid is an executable script with content "#!/bin/bash

id -g"  still that doesnt seem to work. Your explanation was based upon "-" signs but there is no here